# jqGrid - error when JSON has no 'rows' data with jsonReader

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

Using jqGrid with Fusion Tables, if the JSON returns with results it works fine, but if there are no results then because obj.rows doesn't exist, the page breaks when trying to check the length. Is there a way to handle this gracefully?

```
jsonReader: {
            cell: "",
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            records: function (obj) { return obj.rows.length; } 

        },
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

and the JSON:

```
// API callback
jQuery16405104181477800012_1369220882365({
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "id",
  "latitude",
  "longitude",
  "name",
  "address_line_1",
  "address_line_2",
  "address_line_3",
  "postcode"
 ]
}
);
```

and below is an example of a result with rows:

```
jQuery1640010438381228595972_1369222778703({
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "id",
  "latitude",
  "longitude",
  "name",
  "address_line_1",
  "address_line_2",
  "address_line_3",
  "postcode"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "1132584",
   50.55307,
   "-4.19639",
   "The Road",
   "ROAD",
   "Town",
   "CITY",
   "POSTCODE"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just modify `records` function to

```js
records: function (obj) {
    return obj.rows != null ? return obj.rows.length : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem,

I had created a div to show the jqgrid but you must create a table.

I did that and it worked! :)